# Detect what a python string begins with

Tags: python, string

To detect whether a python string ends with a particular substring, say `".txt"`, there is a convenient built-in python string method;

```
 if file_string.endswith(".txt"):
```

I would like to to detect whether a python string begins with a particular substring, say `"begin_like_this"`. I am not able find a convenient method that I can use like this;

```
 if file_string.beginswith("begin_like_this"):
```

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: I did google but used the wrong keyword and could not find useful searches. I used "begin with" instead of "start with".

Comment: Recommending "google it" for API questions is bad advice, for _any_ language. This is what the API docs are for. Break the google/SO cycle (google links to SO, SO says "google it"). Link to the docs (like the accepted answer does.) Forum responsibly.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You're looking for [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

```
if file_string.startswith("begin_like_this"):
```